# DOMSettableTokenList .value

Tags: dom

[w3 DOM4 Spec DOMettableTokenList](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#domsettabletokenlist)

This is poorly explained.

I understood it is a extension for DOMTokenList.

We get DOMTokenList when we write:

```
Element.classList;
```

or:

```
Node.classList;
```

But when do we get DOMSettableTokenList?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMSettableTokenList` was actually [merged into `DOMTokenList`](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/119) in the WHATWG "Living Standard" version of the spec.

The value you get from `.classList` should have (in supporting browsers, [such as Firefox 47](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1244328)) the `.value` property that was defined on `DOMSettableTokenList`. **[upd]** Also setting `.classList = "string"` invokes the `value` setter (splitting the string into tokens and assigning separate classes), which is called `[PutForwards=value]` in the spec.

I believe before the merge, you were still able to access classList.value (in supporting browsers), but I didn't test. **[upd]** [Actually](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/361/files) some attributes were `DOMTokenList` (e.g. `classList`) while others were `DOMSettableTokenList` (e.g. `HTMLLinkElement.relList`)

Comment: Thanks, I think I got confused because I´d tested and it didn´t work, now I know because it is not cross-browser-supported yet.

Comment: @vsenol out of interest, what browser/version did you test? And feel free to accept the answer if it, well, answered your question.

Comment: I generally test with the newest versions of chrome, firefox, ie and opera

Comment: @vsenol: thanks for letting me know, seems I was not completely right. I updated the answer.